# OutOfMemoryException in my application, I tried to use using and dispose()!

Tags: c#, sql-server, out-of-memory

I've just read all the answers about the same problem but they have not helped.

This is a part of my c# code that is too long. It has a lot of `SQLConnection`s and 2 timers.

```
Indirizzo nuovoInd = new Indirizzo();

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(nuovoInd.OttieniIP());
string strSql = "INSERT INTO Pietanze(nome,prezzo,ingredienti,cod_cat) VALUES ('"+nome+"','"+prezzo+"','"+ingredienti+"','"+contCat+"')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, cn);

cn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

or

```
public static float GetCoperti(int codOrdine)
    {
        float copertiTot = 0;
        List<Ordine> ordini = new List<Ordine>();

        VisualizzaOrdini.Form1.Indirizzo nuovoInd = new VisualizzaOrdini.Form1.Indirizzo();

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(nuovoInd.OttieniIP());
        string strSql = "SELECT codo,tavolo,InsertDate,nCoperti,costoCoperti FROM Ordini, Riga_Ordine, Coperti where codo=cod_or and cod_or = '"+ codOrdine + "' ORDER BY InsertDate DESC";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, cn);

        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Ordine currO = new Ordine();
            currO.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["InsertDate"]);
            currO.Coperti = (int)dr["nCoperti"];
            currO.PrezzoCoperto = Convert.ToSingle(dr["costoCoperti"]);
            currO.Tavolo = dr["tavolo"].ToString();
            currO.Codice = (int)dr["codo"];
            copertiTot = (currO.PrezzoCoperto * Convert.ToSingle(currO.Coperti));
            ordini.Add(currO);
        }

        return copertiTot;

    }
```

I'm struggling with the fact that the code is throwing an `OutOfMemoryException`. What might be causing this? How do I resolve it?

Comment: I don't see anywhere a connection.Close and a connection.Dispose. You should read about it, because opening and leaving open this objects could easily be the reason of your memory problem.

Comment: you say you have tried `using` - *where* have you tried `using`? as your question is missing it in three places (`cn`, `cmd`, `dr`).Also: how much data are you querying? is it *in this method* that it is failing? Normally, if the problem related to connections, I would expect to see an error about "timeout obtaining connection from the connection pool" **long** before you see an out-of-memory.

Comment: oooh, SQL injection heaven... `VALUES ('"+nome+"','"+prezzo+"','"+ingredienti+"','"+contCat+"')` that should ***absolutely*** be parameterized to `VALUES (@nome, @prezzo, @ingredienti, @contCat)`. Also, the `SELECT` is almost as bad (although it is an `int`)

Comment: Also; what is `VisualizzaOrdini.Form1.Indirizzo` ? is that some kind of form/control? If so, *I think we have an offender*...

Comment: How many rows does this bring back? I'd suspect the `List` before I'd suspect the connection.

Comment: @Jon the funny thing is: the list (`ordini`) *isn't ever used* (except to add to it), so a simple answer to *that* could be : get rid of the list

Comment: @user1635739 people are asking you necessary questions in order to understand the full context, in order to provide the most appropriate answer; please feel free to jump in and answer them...

Comment: i must say, paste the exception here

Comment: @MarcGravell as given the whole thing could just be found from `SELECT TOP 1 costoCoperti * nCoperti FROM Ordini, Riga_Ordine, Coperti where codo=cod_or and cod_or = '"+ codOrdine + "' ORDER BY InsertDate"` and at least one of those tables could be taken out too. I assume this is a redacted version of the real thing.

Comment: @Jon true, true; I had thought I had seen an accumulator (hence the need to process the rows), but I must have imagined that. Besides, even if there *was* an accumulator, it would be better to ask the db server to handle that.

Comment: What are the `2 timers` doing?

Answer (score 0):

It may be the problem that you are not [Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx) your `SqlDataReader` object after fetching records, You have to close it explicitly.

```
dr.Close();
```

And also, Close your connection after closing reader, or use `using` block as suggested by **Habib**.

```
cn.Close();
```

Comment: `using` would be far preferable, as it would handle exceptions as well as success; the OP claims to have already tried `using`, although it is unclear in what way

Answer (score 0):

First, having your database connection open for the full execution of code is bad practice. Assign the execute statement to some `DataTable`. It will provide you the local copy of the database. It's also more convenient to process and you surely don't get out of memory exceptions.

**Datatable DTab = cmdexecuteReader();
DataSet DSet = cmdexecuteReader();**

Both Will give you expectedd results always.

Comment: The code creates a new connection; sure, it is missing a `Close()`/`using`, but it isn't an application-wide connection. But seriously: `DataTable`? No. Just no. Especially suggesting a "local copy of the Database" - that is just not good.

Comment: That would introduce out of memory where there were none. What with it using lots of memory.

Comment: I can't use a local database, because my program must use a remote sql server. The Pc program reads the data from the database, and the sql database receives the data from an android device. Understand?

Comment: but it is one good and always promising ways to follow. in my experience and in my project we did used data table and it never gone wrong. It can hold as much as memory you u can load it with

Comment: @DineshGuptha no, you can't; trying to mimic the DB in memory is an anti-pattern. I will go on record: if you're doing much `DataTable`, you're *doing it wrong* (with a caveat: if your schema *cannot* be known up-front, it may be an appropriate tool, but should still be tightly scoped and with minimal data)

Comment: I preferred it here because the data here handled seems like with less secured data or common data so once we load it in table we can make use of it through out the page, if you are concerned with security issues we can go for dataset, and even in table we can flush the very data once the usage is over, like in data set